# Nested arrays in Helm Yaml

Tags: json, yaml, kubernetes-helm

Im using Helm.

I have a settings.json file containing the following configuration:

```
"CustomSetting": {
  "ArrayOfArrays": {{ .Values.customSetting.arrayOfArrays | toJson }}
}
```

And my values.yaml file contains the following values:

```
customSetting:
  arrayOfArrays: [
      [ "someValue1", "someValue2" ],
      [ "anotherValue3", "anotherValue4" ]
  ]
```

My problem is that I cannot run my chart with this setup since I get the following error:

*unable to parse YAML: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line X: did not find expected key*

**How do I get this nested array in my settings.json file?**

Comment: Where is the `settings.json` file used?  (Injected into a ConfigMap?)  More specifically, do you use [the `tpl` function](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) to expand the template in the JSON file?  Editing the question to show how you're accessing the `settings.json` file would be helpful.

Comment: (If you're getting an "unable to parse YAML" error, running `helm template --debug .` will show you the raw text of what's being generated, and sometimes it's obvious that something is incorrectly indented or a newline is missing.)

Answer (score 0):

Turn the settings into a [multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines/21699210) by using `|` in yaml. This way your json config isn't processed by helm.

```
customSetting:  
  arrayOfArrays: |
    [
      [ "someValue1", "someValue2" ],
      [ "anotherValue3", "anotherValue4" ]
    ]
```

Now your variable is a string and can be used without any modifiers

```
"CustomSetting": {
  "ArrayOfArrays": {{ .Values.customSetting.arrayOfArrays }}
}
```

Comment: getting an execution error with your setup: *at <.Values.customSetting.arrayOfArrays>: can't evaluate field arrayOfArrays in type interface {}*

Comment: @Hristo I adjusted the snippet. Can you try it again?

Comment: now getting same error as I mentioned on the post: *unable to parse YAML: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line X: did not find expected key*

Comment: If it is of any help I am using **vscode-helm
v0.4.0** to lint the file and helm: **version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.7.1", GitCommit:"1d11fcb5d3f3bf00dbe6fe31b8412839a96b3dc4", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.16.9"}**

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issue, found following way that works for me:

```
  ArrayExample: |
    [
      [
        "asdf1",
        "asdf2"
      ],
      [
        "asdf3",
        "asdf4"
      ]
    ]
```

then the var is called via helm:`"foo": {{ .Values.custom.ArrayExample | toPrettyJson  }}`

Best of luck

Comment: getting an execution error with our setup: *unable to parse YAML: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line X: did not find expected key*